How to use activeOffsetX with Flatlist that contains WebView items to limit the slight horizontal swipe during up/down swipe of the WebView
I have a bunch of htm files in the asset. I want to load each file like a page in a book. I am using a flatlist from react-native-gesture-handler which contains webviews to allow swiping horizontally. Each item is like a whole page of a webview.
Vertical scroll should be handled by the webview and horizontal scroll by the flatlist. The issue I am facing is even a slight horizontal swipe during the vertical swipe will trigger the scrolling of flatlist to the next page. To avoid that, I have wrapped the flatlist with a GestureDetector which should be able to use activeOffsetX prop that can ignore the initial horizontal movement unless it reaches a certain threshold.
However, GestureDetector seems has no effect. Is there anything that I am missing in this code example:
import React from 'react';
import {
  Gesture,
  GestureDetector,
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('screen');

export default function App() {
  const pan = Gesture.Pan().activeOffsetX([-50, 50]).failOffsetY([-5, 5]);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <WebView
      source={{ uri: item.uri }}
      style={{ width: width, height: height }}
      onTouchEnd={(event) => {
        console.log('Touch end', event);
      }}
    />
  );

  const data = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, index) => ({
    key: `${index}`,
    uri: 'https://www.google.com',
  }));

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}>
      <GestureDetector gesture={pan}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.key}
          horizontal
          pagingEnabled
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        />
      </GestureDetector>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});


The Gesture handler library wrappes the flatlist with NativeViewGestureHandler
Ideally, flatlist itself should have the activeOffsetX property so that we can control it directly, but NativeViewGestureHandler does not have such prop. So the only way that I should think of is to use a wrapper and somehow catching the first few points of horizontal gesture and only allow the horizontal gesture to be active in the flatlist when it reaches some threshold.
